# Ruby multiple statements on single line with condition

Tags: ruby, perl

What is the cleanest way to write following code in Ruby?

```
if    ($string eq "dasff1") { print "dasff1" ;print " hoiff1" } 
elsif ($string eq "dasff2") { print "dasff2" ;print " hoiff2" } 
elsif ($string eq "dasff3") { print "dasff3" ;print " hoiff3" }
```

i.e multiple statements on a single line qualified with a condition.

Is there an alternate way other than

```
if    (string == "dasff1") 
  print "dasff1" ;print " hoiff1"
elsif (string == "dasff2") 
  print "dasff2" ;print " hoiff2"
elsif (string == "dasff3") 
  print "dasff3" ;print " hoiff3"
end
```

Comment: Why is this question tagged [tag:perl]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use :

```
string = "dasff1"

case string
when "dasff1" then print "dasff1"; print " hoiff1"
when "dasff2" then print "dasff2"; print " hoiff2"
when "dasff3" then print "dasff3"; print " hoiff3"
end
```

Or just :

```
print string+" "+string.sub('das','hoi') if string=~/^dasff[1-3]$/
```

You shouldn't do that, but since you asked for it :

```
if    string == "dasff1" then print "dasff1" ; print " hoiff1"
elsif string == "dasff2" then print "dasff2" ; print " hoiff2"
elsif string == "dasff3" then print "dasff3" ; print " hoiff3"
end
```

Comment: I think it is more idiomatic to use the `then` keyword to separate the condition part of a conditional expression from the body than to use a semicolon: `if    (string == "dasff1") then print "dasff1" ; print " hoiff1"` …

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to define a mapping table since you're doing straight-up matches:

```
remap = {
  "dasff1" => "hoiff1",
  "dasff2" => "hoiff2",
  "dasff3" => "hoiff3"
}

if (remapped = remap[string])
  puts [ string, remapped ].join(' ')
end
```

Since there's a pattern here you might also do this:

```
if (string.match(/\Adasff(\d+)/)
  puts [ string, 'hoiff%s' % $1 ]
end
```

From a style perspective, try to avoid joining together multiple lines of Ruby code using `;`. It creates a lot of clutter.

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
h = { "dasff1"=>"hoiff1", "dasff2"=>"hoiff2", "dasff3"=>"hoiff3" }
```

compute another hash with a default value equal to an empty string:

```
g = h.each_with_object(Hash.new('')) { |(k,v),g| g[k] = "%s %s" % [k,v] }
  #=> {"dasff1"=>"dasff1 hoiff1", "dasff2"=>"dasff2 hoiff2", "dasff3"=>"dasff3 hoiff3"}
```

Confirm the default:

```
g["cat"]
  #=> ""
```

Then

```
def pr_str(str, g)
  print g[str]
end

print "|"; pr_str("dasff1", g); print "|"
  # |dasff1 hoiff1| 
print "|"; pr_str("dasff2", g); print "|"
  # |dasff2 hoiff2|
print "|"; pr_str("dasff3", g); print "|"
  # |dasff3 hoiff3|
print "|"; pr_str("catsup", g); print "|"
  # ||
```

The `|` characters are printed to demark the start and end of each string returned. Note the `print ''` (as opposed to `puts ''`) does nothing.